# C Programming - Insert value into singly linked list after specific node

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program I have been sweating over and keep getting a segmentation fault on the function insertAfter. I was given the base code and asked to create serveral functions. I have gotten most of them to work, but I cannot get insertAfter to insert a value after a specified node. I haven't worked much on the insertBefore, but am assuming I will have the same problem

So, here is my code: (I have included header node and function that creates a new node as well)

```
struct lnode
{
    int data;
    struct lnode *next;
};


struct lheader
{
    struct lnode *start;
    int len;
};

struct lnode *makenode( int val )
{
    struct lnode *box;
    box = malloc( sizeof( struct lnode ) );
    box->data = val;
    box->next = NULL;
    return box;
}
```

Here is the function:

```
void insertAfter( struct lheader *L, struct lnode *p )
{
    int pos, value;
    struct lnode *nn;
    struct lnode *temp;
    temp = p;
    printf( "What number do you want to insert? " );
    scanf( "%d", &value );
    printf( "Insert after which value: " );
    scanf( "%d", &pos );
    nn = makenode(value);
    if ( L->start == NULL )
    {
         L->start = nn;
    }
    else
    {
         temp = L->start;
         while( temp->next != NULL && temp->data != pos )
         {
             temp = temp->next;
         }
         if ( temp->data == pos )
         {
             nn->next = temp->next;
             temp->next = nn;
             printf("Value is %d: ", nn->data);
         }
         else
         {
             printf( "Value %d is not in list\n", pos );
         }
     }
}
```

I added this in the wrong spot, I think!

Thanks for all your input. I had to pick my kids up and could not get back to the program.

Here is the the main function, as well as the print functions that main calls. I commented out some of the other functions.

```
void printlist( struct lnode *front )
{
    struct lnode *mov;
    mov = front;
    while (mov != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ", mov->data);
        mov = mov->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void printer( struct lheader *alist )
{
    struct lnode *mov;
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("List print, len %d\n", alist->len);
    printlist( alist->start );
    printf("--------------------------\n");
}


int main()
{
    struct lheader *L;
    struct lnode  *head, *tmp;
    struct lnode  *mark;
    int i, x;

L = makelist();

for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
{
    x = rand() % 25 + 1;
    printf("-- Adding -- %d\n", x);
    //insertFront( L, x );
    insertBack( L, x, i );
    printer( L );
}


printf(">>>>Value to search: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
i = isInList(L, x);
printf("I is %d\n", i);
tmp = findNode(L, x);
if (tmp == NULL)
{     
    printf("NOPE\n");
{
else
{ 
    printf("Found node %d\n", tmp->data);
{ 
insertAfter( L, mark );
// printer( L );
// insertBefore( L, mark );
// printer( L );
return 0;
}
```

I tried a debugger (first time) and it said the segmentation fault is at temp = temp->next in the below snippet of code:

```
else
{
     temp = L->start;
     while( temp->next != NULL && temp->data != pos )
     {
         temp = temp->next;
     }
     if ( temp->data == pos )
     {
         nn->next = temp->next;
         temp->next = nn;
         printf("Value is %d: ", nn->data);
     }
     else
     {
         printf( "Value %d is not in list\n", pos );
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Try using a debugger. Step through the code.

Comment: What are you expected to do with the parameter `p`? You should probably check whether `L` is null and also whether `nn` is null after the call to `makenode`.

Comment: Can you share your `main` function code so we know how this is called? Your function didn't seg fault for me.

Comment: Could you point out which line the fault is occurring on? Without everything, this is difficult to diagnose, because it looks like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the above conditions like this:

- value: Data to be inserted.
- loc: Location after which data is to be inserted.

---

```
void insertAfter(int value,int loc)
{
    struct node* newNode;
    newNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data=value;

  if(head==NULL)
    {
      newNode->next=NULL;
      head=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->data==loc)
            {
                newNode->next=temp->next;
                temp->next=newNode;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
        if(temp->next==NULL)
            printf("Location not found");
    }
    printf("New Node inserted successfully after %d",loc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Inserting At Specific location in the list (After a Node):

-We can use the following steps to insert a new node after a node in the single linked list...

1. Create a newNode with given value.
2. Check whether list is Empty (head == NULL)
3. If it is Empty then, set newNode → next = NULL and head = newNode.
4. If it is Not Empty then, define a node pointer temp and initialize with head.
5. Keep moving the temp to its next node until it reaches to the node after which we want to insert the newNode (until temp1 → data is equal to location, here location is the node value after which we want to insert the newNode).
6. Every time check whether temp is reached to last node or not. If it is reached to last node then display 'Given node is not found in the list!!! Insertion not possible!!!' and terminate the function. Otherwise move the temp to next node.
7. Finally, Set 'newNode → next = temp → next' and 'temp → next = newNode'

   ```
   void insertAfter(int value,int loc)
       {
           struct node* newNode;
           newNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
           newNode->data=value;

         if(head==NULL)
           {
             newNode->next=NULL;
             head=newNode;
           }
           else
           {
               struct node* temp=head;
               while(temp->next!=NULL)
               {
                   if(temp->data==loc)
                   {
                       newNode->next=temp->next;
                       temp->next=newNode;
                       break;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       temp=temp->next;
                   }
               }
               if(temp->next==NULL)
                   printf("Location not found");
           }
           printf("New Node inserted successfully after %d",loc);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you're while loop looks a little off to me.

```
 while( temp->next != NULL && temp->data != pos )
```

If I'm not mistaken, you're using pos as the index of the element you want to add a new node after. However, here, you're comparing it to the value of the temp node. It seems to me that you should be comparing it to a count of how many times you have iterated to the next node. I think your problems are stemming from that.

It's possible I am interpreting your variable naming incorrectly though.

Comment: I have a feeling the OP abandoned the thread when it was closed on Programmers. We'll never know what the real problem was.

Comment: Dan - in this case I am asking for which value the next value should be inserted after and traversing the list until that value is found. My first 20 drafts I was asking which position to add the value after and using the iteration method, but I changed it in desperation when I could not figure out what the problem was! I kept the same variable name. Probably the first method was better, as that ended up not being the problem!